# How to make auth login in laravel by using roll number of student instead of email

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to make the auth login for students, but i want them to login with their Roll numbers instead of using their emails. I have seen the logins with username instead of emails but couldn't find anything other then these. Please Help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Nope! i havent found anthing yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the email column for password resets and only apply the rollnumber for login
Add this to your LoginController

```
Public function username(){
    return 'columnname';
}
```

Set the `columnname` to column on your users table that you want. It would override the default set in `AuthenticatesUsers` class